# Duplicate Class Found Bouncy Castle Android

Tags: java, android, gradle

I keep getting this error. I have tried these codes in app/build-gradle:

```
android {
    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'bcprov-jdk15on'
        all*.exclude module: 'bcutil-jdk15on'
    }
```

**Gradle JDK**

Jbr 17.0.9

**Gradle**

```
version gradle-7.5-bin
```

**Plugin**

```
  id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
  id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
```

**Bouncy Castle:**

```
  implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15to18:1.77'
  implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.77'

 Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.x509.PKIXCRLUtil found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.77) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.77)
    Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.x509.PKIXCertPathReviewer found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.77) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.77)
    Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.x509.X509Attribute found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.77) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.77)
    Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.x509.X509AttributeCertStoreSelector found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.77) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.77)
    Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.x509.X509AttributeCertificate found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.77) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.77)
    Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.x509.X509CRLStoreSelector found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.77) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.77)
    Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.x509.X509CertPairStoreSelector found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.77) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.77)
    Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.x509.X509CertStoreSelector found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.77) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.77)
    Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.x509.X509CertificatePair found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.77) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.77)
    Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.x509.X509CollectionStoreParameters found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.77) and jetified-bcprov-jdk18on-1.77 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.77)
```

**SOLVED** with those lines in app/build-gradle

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'bcprov-jdk15to18'
    all*.exclude module: 'bcutil-jdk18on'
    all*.exclude module: 'bcprov-jdk15on'
    all*.exclude module: 'bcutil-jdk15on'
}
```